# Metapost - Color portions of a curve with different colors

Tags: metapost

I searched a bit and didn't find something that relates to this.

> Suppose I created a closed curve in Metapost with the command `p:=z_1..z_2..z_3..cycle`. Is it possible to color pieces of this curve using different colors? How can I define a subset of this curve?

I was thinking that maybe there is a parametric representation of `p` which would enable me to color with another color the part from `z_1` to `z_2` for example.

It would really help if I could do the above, because I want to attach other figures to the colored portions of the curve.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to specify parts of a path. One way is to use the `cutbefore` and `cutafter` statements as illustrated here:

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
    % define points
    z_0 := origin;
    z_1 := (0cm, .5cm);
    z_2 := (3cm, 1cm);
    z_3 := (5cm, 3.5cm);
    z_4 := (2cm, 3cm);
    z_5 := (1cm, 2cm);

    % define paths
    path p;
    p := z_1 .. z_2 .. z_3 .. z_4 .. z_5 .. cycle;
    path s;
    s := p cutbefore point 3 of p .. p cutafter point 1 of p;

    % draw lines
    draw p withpen pencircle scaled 8pt withcolor blue;
    draw s withpen pencircle scaled 4pt withcolor yellow;

    % draw the points and labels
    pickup pencircle scaled 8pt;
    for x=0 upto 4:
        draw point x of p;
        label.bot(decimal(x), point x of p);
    endfor;
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: result]

For more information I would suggest reading the [MetaFun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf). MetaFun is an extension to MetaPost. Anyhow, there are many examples included (see chapters one and two) that will also work with plain MetaPost.